# Perl one-liner: how to skip to the next file in @ARGV

Tags: perl

I was thinking about how to "short circuit" reading a file within a `perl -ne` loop. If I hit some condition, I want to abandon the current file and proceed to the next one in @ARGV. This would be similar to GNU awk's  handy [`nextfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html) command.

Something like this:

```
perl -ne 'do_something(); next_file if some_condition()' files ...
```

Playing around, I found that `close ARGV` achieves the "go to next file" goal.

Are there other, less magical, ways to accomplish this?

Comment: `close ARGV` has a side effect of resetting `$.`, as documented in [`perldoc -f eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html)

Comment: So are you asking how to skip to the next file without resetting `$.`?

Comment: No, I was just commenting.

Comment: It's hard to imagine a scenario where you wouldn't want `$.` reset when opening a new file. The default behavior is sane. If you don't want it reset, it should require a workaround (which would be trivial)

Comment: @stevieb The default behavior with `-n`/`-p` (i.e. if you don't explicitly close `ARGV`) is to not reset `$.`: `echo foo > foo; echo bar > bar; perl -nE'say $.' foo bar`.

Comment: I learn something new every day :) "that was easy!"

Comment: you can't even localize $. to protect it, since local $. does something special

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, close ARGV is the right way to do this.

As noted by glenn jackman, this has the side effect of resetting your `$.` line counter (which normally continues incrementing across several files when using ARGV), so you may want to save and restore it:

```
my $line = $.;
close ARGV;
$. = $line;
```

Comment: Personally, I would leave `$.` alone, but keep a separate variable to count the cumulative number of records seen. `perl -ne '$all_nr++; do_stuff; close ARV if something'`